# Reference required: critical points of nonconstant holomorphic functions are isolated

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Can anyone find the precise statement and proof for this theorem (for several variable case)?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it true for $f(z_1, z_2) = z_1^2$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Ohh you are right. I guess the staement only holds for single-variable case.